# Getting KeyError after running json.loads

Tags: python, json, keyerror

I want to change the ID value in the loop, from 0 to 100, and then download these pictures, but in the loop, it reported an error and the dictionary value was not found.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import json
import os
import urllib

if not os.path.exists('images'):
    os.mkdir('images')


def huluxia(id=250):
    _key = '**'
    hlx = requests.get(url='**',
                       params={'_key': _key,
                               'user_id': id})
    hlx.encoding = 'utf-8'
    hlx_json = json.loads(hlx.content)
    print(hlx_json['avatar'])
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(hlx_json['avatar'], './images/%s%s.jpg' %
                               (hlx_json['nick'], hlx_json['userID']))

for i in range(100):
    huluxia(id=i)
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: It seems that the `avatar` key doesn't exist in the dictionary.
You can use `hlx_json.get('avatar')` to avoid this exception(it would return `None` type as a default value, and you can pass another default as a second argument to `get`)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `avatar` key doesn't exist in the dictionary. You can use `hlx_json.get('avatar')` to avoid this exception(it would return None type as a default value, and you can pass another default as a second argument to get)

Another possibility is that the API you're using limits the number of calls on a specific time period and the 100'th call gets rejected. You can test this by starting from the ID 100, or printing the response before the JSON deserialization

Comment: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @Demikozo4 could you please share your changed code segment here?